# What plugin control html_attributes?

Tags: theming

The html.html.twig template contains the following line.

```
<html{{ html_attributes }}>
```

On my site, it outputs the following markup.

```
<html lang="ru" dir="ltr" xmlns:article="http://ogp.me/ns/article#" xmlns:book="http://ogp.me/ns/book#" xmlns:product="http://ogp.me/ns/product#" xmlns:profile="http://ogp.me/ns/profile#" xmlns:video="http://ogp.me/ns/video#" prefix="content: http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/  dc: http://purl.org/dc/terms/  foaf: http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/  og: http://ogp.me/ns#  rdfs: http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#  schema: http://schema.org/  sioc: http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#  sioct: http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#  skos: http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#  xsd: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema# ">
```

What plugin or core function controls it?

Answer (score 1):

They're added in [`template_preprocess_html`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/8.2.x):

```
$variables['html_attributes'] = new Attribute();
```

To alter them, you can implement `hook_preprocess_html` in your theme or module.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal core provides theme "html"
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/8.2.x
See drupal_common_themes().

This is sent thru a preprocess function: hook_preprocess_html()
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/8.2.x

In the preprocess function, the "html_attributues" variable is added by using the Attribute class;
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21Attribute.php/class/Attribute/8.2.x

Theming is a huge part of Drupal, here's a good starting point
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming

More info on preprocess functions
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-best-practices-preprocess-functions-and-templates

More info on using attributes
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/using-attributes-in-templates

Answer (score -2):

I think it is a result of working "Metatag" module (your attributes contain some w3c validation errors). I used [this patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2753595) to change depreciated metatags.